# Get number of directives on page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

Is there a way with angular that we can get the current number of directives on a page before it processes?

Currently, I'm using jQuery:

```
function getNumberOfSlots() {
    var slots = [];
    $('slot-field').each(function() {
        slots.push(parseInt($(this).attr('pos')));
    });
    return slots.length;
}
```

Just curious if there's a way internal that angular will be able to tell, obviously at somepoint it will have to loop over each one and process them, just wondering if it saves that data internally before it processes and if I'm able to expose it.

The reason I'm after this information, is so that I can broadcast an event when it's processing the LAST directive on the page for the slot-field directive.

Is this possible or should I keep using jquery?

Comment: I'm not sure if angular has a way to get all of the directives on the page. Especially if you're just looking for the custom ones. I would make the suggestion however that rather then use the jquery $ use angular.element it inherits from jquery so it has the same functions but it won't cause problems with the angular method of naming variables with a $ or cause problems with when angular tries to use the jquery object. It isn't a necessity but it might help prevent bugs

Comment: @Binvention I good suggestion, still doesn't really answer my question :(

Comment: Are you just trying to get the custom directives?

Comment: Basically, I just want to get the number of slot-directives on the page before the app-cycle. Rather than just use that jquery loop to get the number of directives. I know that angular saves the directives under the _invokeQueue, but it doesn't say how many, just it's params

Comment: For your purpose of it are you using an ng-repeat for your slot directives? And is it possible you could just define a new service instead?

Comment: No Unfortunately they're dynamically drawn from the backend in random locations!